# EventAggregator for .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, eventaggregator

In my .net 2.0 Win Forms application I want to raise something like OnProgress event from many different places/classes, and handle all these events in one place.

We're using Microsoft's UnityContainer for dependency injection, and I saw a good solution for the problem I have in EventAggregator from Composite Application Library.

Could you please advice me something similar to EventAggregator, that will work under .net 2.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read some recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343980/event-aggregator-implementation-sample-best-practices)

Comment: thanks, that helped. There are a lot of useful things about event aggregation, but probably there's no exact solution. So, I invented my own bicycle for this :)